# bluetoothd fails at "set secure simple pairing"

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, intel, adapter

My `bluetoothd` logs a failure in the syslog after waking up from a sleep of my laptop:

```
Jun 25 12:54:34 lati bluetoothd[718]: Adapter /org/bluez/718/hci0 has been disabled
Jun 25 12:54:34 lati bluetoothd[718]: Unregister path: /org/bluez/718/hci0
Jun 25 12:54:34 lati bluetoothd[718]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.59 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun 25 12:54:34 lati bluetoothd[718]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.59 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun 25 12:54:34 lati bluetoothd[718]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.59 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Jun 25 12:54:34 lati bluetoothd[718]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.59 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Jun 25 12:54:34 lati bluetoothd[718]: Adapter /org/bluez/718/hci0 has been enabled
Jun 25 12:54:34 lati bluetoothd[718]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.59 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Jun 25 12:54:34 lati bluetoothd[718]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.59 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Jun 25 12:54:34 lati bluetoothd[718]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.59 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun 25 12:54:34 lati bluetoothd[718]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.59 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun 25 12:54:34 lati bluetoothd[718]: Unknown command complete for opcode 19
Jun 25 12:54:34 lati bluetoothd[718]: hci0: Set Secure Simple Pairing (0x000b) failed: Busy (0x0a)
```

My system info:

- Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (trusty)
- Architecture: 64 bit
- Kernel version: 3.16.0-40-generic
- Dell E7440
- Bios version: A14
- Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq